# Setting a private struct as a return value

Tags: c++, struct

For a class assignment, we are required to have a private struct in a class, but we need to have the same struct as a return value (not a pointer to it). Something along these lines:

```
private:
    struct Employee 
    {
        int id;
        string name;    
    };

public:
    struct Employee find(int key);
```

Is this possible using exclusively the STL?

Comment: Yes, it is possible. And this has nothing to do with STL.

Comment: C++ does not use the `struct` keyword for type-names (besides declarations).

Comment: `employee` is not `Employee`.

Comment: Your `Employee` struct is not immutable, so returning an instance of it would be a bad design (unless you really want to return a mutable copy).

Comment: and you are allowed to write save the call result in a variable declared with auto keyword.

Comment: forgive me, returning Employee was the goal. I originally had declared a employee of type Employee.

Comment: Do you need to only use the STL?  This may be difficult.

Comment: @ Thomas - yes, as far as I know. our prof did explicitly say "no boost"

Comment: @Krick Boost and the STL are totally different things.

Comment: @Dai You are wrong about the keyword struct. Elaborated names are used very often in C++.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow I learned something today! However it's used to disambiguate code, which isn't necessary in this context - where instead it looks like a carryover from C instead of being idiomatic C++.

Comment: @Dai, yes, very much so. I just wanted to avoid any sort of dissolution of this thread into a boost dialogue.

Answer (score 0):

It can be done but does not make great sense because the interface should be public.

For example

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

struct C
{
private:
    struct Employee 
    {
        int id;
        std::string name;    
    };

    Employee e = { 1, "First" };

public:
    Employee find(int key) const
    {
        return key == e.id ? e : Employee {};
    }
};

int main() 
{
    C c;

    auto e = c.find( 1 );

    std::cout << e.name << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
First
```