# Reach private struct from public function prototype

Tags: c++, struct, header

I would like to understand why compiler does not figure out private struct in public function. For example:

```
class List
{
public:
  List();
  List(const List&);
  bool remove(int);
  bool insert(int, ItemType );
  Node *find(int);
  void toString();
  ItemType retrive(int);
  int getSize();
private:
    struct Node
    {
        ItemType item;
        Node *next;
    };
  int size;
    Node *head;

};
```

In this code, which is portion of a Linked List header, gnu compiler gives me this error:

> error: unknown type name 'Node'
>     Node *find(int);

I found a topic related with this issue but I do not understand why it works.
[Setting a private struct as a return value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40824404/setting-a-private-struct-as-a-return-value).

Comment: `Node` is undeclared at the time `Node *find(int);` is encountered. Move the definition of it (or forward-declare it) to the top of the `class`.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude - `auto *n = list.find(2);` Yep, placeholder type deduction makes it usable. Though it's a bit evil.

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although many relate `C++` as an object oriented programming language; that is only but a small subset of the language core. This paradigm can get some people into trouble because `C++` at its roots just like `C` is a procedural programming language.

Consider this snippet of code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main() {
    std::string hello("hello");
    std::string world("world");

    std::string helloWorld = getConcatString( hello, world );

    std::cout << helloWorld << std::endl;
    return 0;
}

std::string getConcatString( const std::string& str1, const std::string& str2 ) {
    return str1 + std::string(" ") + str2;
}
```

The above will not compile, this will fail when it reaches the `8th` line in this code. This fails for the same reason as it does in your class. The compiler comes across `getConcatString(...)` yet it is not declared nor defined before hand as C++ is a procedural language at its core. This is why you need a forward declaration before a `function`, `struct`, `class`, etc. is used. The compiler needs to know how much memory to set aside and needs to know what type of memory it is going to allocate either it be local, dynamic, static, const etc. Everything in C++ happens in a sequence of order.

---

To fix the above code you have two options:

- Define the function, class, struct etc. before they are used.
- Or Have a function prototype, or class forward declaration that is before its use.

---

When it comes to a class's structure I typically follow this pattern:

```
class ClassName /*struct StructName*/ {
public:
    // variables, constants, enums, structs, unions, typedefs here

protected:
    // variables, enums, structs, unions, typedefs here if using inheritance

private:
    // variables, enums, structs, unions, typedefs here to encapsulate

public:
    // Constructors & Destructor if being declared here.
  
    // public functions or methods, setters & getters here.

protected:
    // Constructor - Copy Constructor if Abstract - Inheriting.
    // protected methods for inheriting classes.

private:
    // Constructor - If fully preventing from creating an instance of this class or if the class is fully static.

    // private methods that are specific to this class.

}; // ClassName /*struct StructName*/
```

This way if there are any internal structs or classes within a class or struct it helps to prevent the problem that you are having.

---

---

**EDIT**

I would also like to add that if a class contains an object and manages it's resource with dynamic memory on the heap via pointer then it is better to have a forward declaration of that class in the containing class's header file, then include the resource's header file in the containing class's cpp file as such:

**Foo.h**

```
#ifndef FOO_H
#define FOO_H

class Bar; // forward declaration

class Foo {
private:
    Bar* bar_; // For demonstration purposes I'm using a raw pointer...
               // It is wiser to use smart pointers.

public:
    Foo( /*properties to create an instance of Bar*/ );
    ~Foo(); // Destructor Implemented see Rule of 3, 4 or 5...

    // Copy Construct & overloaded operator=() needed here
    ...

    // other public functions
}; // Foo

#endif // FOO_H
```

**Foo.cpp**

```
#include "Foo.h";
#include "Bar.h"; 

Foo::Foo( /* properties need for Foo & to properly create Bar on the heap*/ ) {
    // Allocation of Bar Here
}

Foo::~Foo() {
    // deallocation of Bar here.
}
```

---

Other wise if Foo is using bar as a local internal instance, copy or reference that is local to Foo and is independent of Bar meaning that Bar does not include Foo or have any access to Foo's internals then it is safe to just include Bar's header in Foo's Header as such:

**Foo.h**

```
#ifndef FOO_H
#define FOO_H

#include "Bar.h"

class Foo {
private:
    Bar bar_; // local stack copy

public:
    Foo(){} // Default - Empty Class

    // Any of these constructors would be okay
    explicit Foo( Bar bar ); 
    explicit Foo( Bar& bar );
    explicit Foo( const Bar bar );
    explicit Foo( const Bar& bar );  
}; // Foo

#endif // FOO_H
```

**Foo.cpp**

```
#include "Foo.h"
// Do not need to include Bar.h

// Constructors here.
```

This pertains to the use of forward declarations but it is also tied into the prevention of circular includes.

Comment: s/it is better/it is POSSIBLE (but not generally a good idea)/g
Instead of raw pointers that own objects, use smart pointers to own objects.

Comment: Yes it is better to use smart pointers, but I was just using raw pointers as a demonstration of the forward declaration...

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf I added a comment in the class declaration with the pointer.

Answer (score 2):

In C++ every name used, such as `Node`, must have been previously declared, i.e. earlier in the source code. There is an exception for the bodies of member functions. You can think of this exception as a textual transformation that's applied before the compilation proper, where the function /definitions/, if any, are moved to a point after the class definition, with only a declaration left in the class. Thus a reference to `Node` in a function body would be OK (treated *as if* it was after that hypothetical transformation). But not in the return value specification.

This means that you can address the issue by reordering your class definition:

```
class List
{
    struct Node
    {
        ItemType item;
        Node *next;
    };
    int size;
    Node *head;
public:
    List();
    List(const List&);
    bool remove(int);
    bool insert(int, ItemType );
    Node *find(int);
    void toString();
    ItemType retrive(int);
    int getSize();
};
```

Answer (score 0):

In C++ language the contexts that can "look ahead" and see the entire class definition are limited to: member function bodies, default arguments, exception specifications and in-class non-static data member initializers.

I.e. for the above reason the following example is legal<sup>†</sup>

```
struct S
{
  void foo(void *p = (N *) 0) throw(N)
  {
    N n;
  }

  unsigned s = sizeof(N);

  struct N {};
};
```

even though it uses name `N` above (i.e. before) its point of declaration.

In your example you are attempting to use a yet-undeclared name `Node` in a *function return type*. Function return type does not belong to the above list. So, this is not allowed in C++. Declare `Node` *before* using it in function return types.

---

<sup>†</sup> GCC refuses to compile the exception specification `throw(N)`, while Clang is perfectly happy with it. Maybe it has something to do with deprecation of this language feature.